# drf - use serializers only for post() method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am using Django Rest Framework. I have defined a serializer - ReceiptLog with no model, which should create entries in TestCaseCommandRun and TestCaseCommandRunResults when a post() request is made to receipt log. Receipt log doesn't exist in the database, I am using it just as an endpoint to accept a combined payload and create entries in underlying tables. I do not want a get() request for the ReceiptLog serializer.

Below are the code snippets.

Issues:

1. How to ensure I have only post() working and get() returns an exception
2. Is using serializers the best approach? or should I use viewsets?
3. I have a browsable API which lists all the api's in urls.py. So when I click on receipt log api, it should not display any data, as get() is not allowed. How do I ensure this?

models.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRun(models.Model):
   # fields
   class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'test_case_command_run'
      unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name', 'suite_run_id', 'case_name', 'command_name'),)


class TestCaseCommandRunResults(models.Model):
    # fields
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_case_command_run_results'
        unique_together = (('suite_run_id', 'command_run_id', 'rule_name', 'result_id'),)
```

views.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRunViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet.objects.values(team_name','suite_name','suite_run_id', 'case_name','command_name','command_run_id','run_start','run_end','result','run_status')
    serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet

class TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet.objects.values('suite_run_id','command_run_id','rule_name', 'result_id',
                                                           'result','expected_values','actual_values','report_values','extended_values')
    serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet

class ReceiptLogViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.ReceiptLog
```

serializers.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet
        fields = ['suite_run_id','command_run_id','rule_name', 'result_id','result','expected_values','actual_values','report_values','extended_values']

class TestCaseCommandRunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestCaseCommandRunSerializer
        fields = [team_name','suite_name','suite_run_id', 'case_name','command_name','command_run_id','run_start','run_end','result','run_status']

class ReceiptLogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):    
    team_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    suite_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    suite_run_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=False, allow_blank=True, default=datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    case_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    command_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    command_run_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=False, allow_blank=True, default='Not Applicable')
    run_start = serializers.DateTimeField()
    run_end = serializers.DateTimeField()
    result = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, default='Not Applicable')
    run_status = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
    rule_name = serializers.CharField( max_length=50, required=False, allow_blank=True,  default='Not Applicable')
    expected_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    actual_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    report_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    extended_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

def create(self, validated_data):
    command_run_data_list = []
    command_run_results_data_list = []
    raw_data_list = []
    many = isinstance(validated_data, list)
    if many:
        raw_data_list = validated_data
    else:
        raw_data_list.append(validated_data)
    result_id = 1
    for data_row in raw_data_list:
        new_command_run_entry = {
            'team_name': data_row.get('team_name'),
            'suite_name': data_row.get('suite_name'),
            'suite_run_id': data_row.get('suite_run_id'),
            'case_name': data_row.get('case_name'),
            'command_name': data_row.get('command_name'),
            'command_run_id': data_row.get('command_run_id'),
            'run_start': data_row.get('run_start'),
            'run_end': data_row.get('run_end'),
            'result': data_row.get('result'),
            'run_status': data_row.get('run_status')
        }
        command_run_data_list.append(new_command_run_entry)
        new_command_run_result_entry = {
            'suite_run_id': data_row.get('suite_run_id'),
            'command_run_id': data_row.get('command_run_id'),
            'rule_name': data_row.get('rule_name'),
            'result_id': result_id,
            'result': data_row.get('result'),  # PASS or FAIL
            'expected_values': data_row.get('expected_values'),
            'actual_values': data_row.get('actual_values'),
            'report_values': data_row.get('report_values'),
            'extended_values': data_row.get('extended_values')
        }

        command_run_results_data_list.append(new_command_run_result_entry)
        result_id += 1

    CommandRunResultSerializer = \
        TestCaseCommandRunResultsSerializer(
            data=command_run_results_data_list,
            many=isinstance(command_run_results_data_list, list))
    CommandRunResultSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(CommandRunResultSerializer)

    CommandRunSerializer = \
        TestCaseCommandRunSerializer(
            data=command_run_data_list,
            many=isinstance(command_run_data_list, list))
    CommandRunSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(CommandRunSerializer)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'test_case_command_runs', views.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet)
router.register(r'test_case_command_run_results', views.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet)
router.register(r'receipt_log', views.ReceiptLogViewSet, base_name='ReceiptLog')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^buildInfo', views.build_info),
    url(r'^isActive', views.is_active),
    url(r'^dqf_api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views in DRF are quite modular that you can just choose to use only the HTTP methods you want. In your case, the best option is to use the `CreateAPIView`.

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView


class ReceiptLogView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ReceiptLog
```

This will also ensure that when GET or other methods are used, then a 405 method not allowed is returned, even in the browsable API

I don't really understand your second question since views(and viewsets) and serializers serve different purposes and are not interchanble.

I would also advice that you improve your naming. Serializer names should end in `Serializer` so as not to confuse them with models.

Comment: I made the changes. However, it still doesn't work. I get the error - 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions' even after adding   @classmethod
    def get_extra_actions(cls):
        return []
to the viewsets

Comment: I was able to fix this, by changing the urls.py. However, now it shows me TypeError at /receipt_log/
'module' object is not callable

Comment: Was ale to resolve all the issues. There was naming issue in the serializers file and hence the correct code wasn't been referred. Thank you for the help

Comment: @snehasalvi just saw your comments now. I'm glad you were able to resolve the issues

Answer (score 0):

I updated my urls.py to include the below line

`url(r'^dqf_api/ReceiptLog/', views.ReceiptLogView.ReceiptLogViewSet.as_view(), name='ReceiptLog')`